# Passing chromeOptions to RemoteDriver, with Python bindings

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to include a few of the chromeOptions for my chrome style RemoteDriver.

I've created a `DesiredCapabilities` dictionary by copying the existing Chrome dictionary and I'm trying to add in my own options using a `ChromeOptions()` object.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

class RemoteDriverStartService():

    chrome = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("Proxy", "null")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["ignore-certificate-errors"])
    chrome["chrome.options"] = options

    def start_driver(self):
        return webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', 
                                desired_capabilities=self.chrome)
```

The above throws an exception that the JSON cannot be serialised. I believe that this is due to the `chrome["chrome.options"]` line but I can't work out what I need to use instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

class RemoteDriverStartService():

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("Proxy", "null")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["ignore-certificate-errors"])
    caps = options.to_capabilities()  # Here's the interesting part :)

    def start_driver(self):
        return webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', 
                                desired_capabilities=self.caps)
```